# How does Garbage Collector frees up memory before JVM exits?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I've read that Garbage Collector runs as a `daemon` thread in java, and daemon threads have low priority and they run in the background supporting other non-daemon threads and that's why `JVM` doesn't wait for daemon threads to finish their execution.

In a situation where if all `non-daemon` threads have exited but there's still some amount of memory occupied then how does `Garbage Collector` manage to free up resources before the JVM stops without causing any memory leaks?

Comment: If a process stops it does not need to clean its own memory, the OS simply frees it up when the process is done. Same for Java: the GC does not need to run, the OS simply terminates the java process and frees up any still occupied memory.

Comment: @luk2302 That's exactly what I was guessing but on wikipedia it says "a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations[1] in a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released"

Comment: That is true but has nothing to do with the question. The OS does not care about your application's potential memory leaks. Your application might freeze up because it messes up its own memory and if the OS detects this or the user detects it and quits the application the OS terminates the application and reclaims is memory, end of story. Of course the OS itself could have a memory leak at which point the OS might "terminate" at some point by basically restarting the computer. You have different levels of applications and memory leaks / management happen on all these levels separately.

Comment: There is a difference between the chunk of memory assigned to the JVM by the operating system, and how the JVM itself manages objects inside that memory (which is what the GC operates on) including finalizers.  When the JVM stops everything is released back to the operating system.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that makes it much clearer! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GC does NOT free up memory before the JVM exits.

What actually happens is that when the JVM exits, the process that the JVM runs in also exits<sup>1</sup>.  When the process exits, the operating system reclaims all of the RAM and swap pages that the process was using (exclusively) and reclaims its virtual memory page tables.

If your Java program (or C / C++ program) has memory leaks, that doesn't matter once the process is cleaned up.  The OS knows at all time which RAM / swap pages belong to which process.  Nothing is lost.

---

<sup>1 - If the JVM was started by a C / C++ application using (say) JNI, then the process won't necessarily exit at that point.  It would then be up to the C / C++ application to figure out what to do.  But the GC doesn't clean up in this case either.</sup>

Comment: Even without exiting the process, there wouldn’t be a problem to release the entire heap memory as a single chunk, the same way it had been allocated.

Comment: Does `JNI_DestroyJavaVM()` do that?

Comment: I wouldn’t bet on it for the reference implementation. The Hotspot JVM doesn’t support more than one JVM for a process not even one after another. This led to such hilarious things like [the documentation of `JNI_DestroyJavaVM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#destroyjavavm) starting with “Unloads a Java VM…” and ending with “Unloading of the VM is not supported”. So how much can we count on the “…and reclaims its resources”? I don’t know.